# How to find word in python?

Tags: python

I have list of strings and have to find specific text from string.
example

```
L1=["Address:S/O: Puran Mal Saini, xxxxxxxxxx,Pxxxxxxxx, Palam Vilxxxxxxiage,Palam",
    "Address:S/O Radheyshyam Sharma, E SECOND",
    "Address:S/O: Saroj Shahi, gram-shyampur",
    "Address:S/O Birjraj Singh, Cccxxxx, NEW Azzzzzzz,",
    "Address:208027 S/O: Naresh Chandra Mishra",
    "Address: C/O: Mayenk Jain. 260/18, Axxxxxxxr, Opp. Haxxxx xxxxxr, Gxxxxxa",
    "Address:208027S/O: Naresh Chandra Mishra,Wxxx, 127/406",
    "Address: C/O Sachin Vasant Shivaji Vidhyalay, Sissssss",
    "Address S/OGanesh Lal Dev, LOT NO-227, NXXXXXXXXX",
    "Address S/O,Ganesh Lal Dev, LOT NO-227, XXXCCCVVVVVVV"]
```

My desire output from above list

```
 Puran Mal Saini,
 Radheyshyam Sharma
 Saroj Shahi
 Birjraj Singh
 Naresh Chandra Mishra
 Mayenk Jain
 Naresh Chandra Mishra
 Sachin Vasant Shivaji Vidhyalay
 Ganesh Lal Dev
 Ganesh Lal Dev
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Your source data is very messy and you should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(".+?(?:[CS]\/O).*?([\w ]+).*", re.IGNORECASE)

print([pattern.findall(x)[0].strip() for x in L1])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['Puran Mal Saini', 'Radheyshyam Sharma', 'Saroj Shahi', 'Birjraj Singh', 'Naresh Chandra Mishra', 'Mayenk Jain', 'Naresh Chandra Mishra', 'Sachin Vasant Shivaji Vidhyalay', 'Ganesh Lal Dev', 'Ganesh Lal Dev']
```

You can avoid the `strip` in your list comprehension if you use:

```
pattern = re.compile(".+?(?:[CS]\/O).*?(\w[\w ]+).*", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Anyway - I do agree with one of the comments: your data source looks extremely messed up, and I am not sure if this pattern will work for other lines I have not seen.